# Entity Framework - reorder elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I just want to change 'Order' value for both elements, I have the following code:

```
        int tmpItemOrder = item1.Order;
        item1.Order = item2.Order;
        item2.Order = tmpItemOrder;

        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

but I get unique key problem (Order is unique key)

> {"Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_EscortItems'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'dbo.EscortItems'. The duplicate key value is
>   (2, 20).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

as I understood, it throws the error when system try to set a dublicate key even inside a transaction. Strange behavior, but as is.

How to solve this problem correctly?

Comment: At a guess, if the values are updated sequentially, as soon as the first one is set it will immediately violate the unique key constraint. Even two `SaveChanges` calls will have the same effect. You will probably have to use an intermediate unique value.

Comment: The other thought is that it is unusual to swap keys over and perhaps the problem needs a different approach - just a thought.

Comment: @PeterSmith, you are right, even two SaveChanges calls have the same effect!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unique constraint must be obeyed at **every row** update, not only when the transaction is done. Attempting to reorder the rows require a careful algorithm. In order to update a row to have the desired 'order' X you must first ensure X is free (ie. no row has already this order). If a row already has this desired order you must move it out of this 'slot' by updating it to a 'free' value (I leave as an exercise for you do find such a 'free' value). Apply this for every row, before updating the 'order'.

It would be *much* simpler to delete all rows and then insert them back in the desired 'order'.

That being said, there are *many* reasons why you don't want to persist 'order' in a column. To mention just one, you *will* have to deal with gaps.

Comment: Linked list (ie. keep a 'next item id' column for each row) is easy to update, but tough to query *in order* (unless you're willing to sort the items client side, in the app, which is feasible for small sets, eg. invoice or 'cart')

Comment: You could also dispense with the UNIQUE constraint, it makes updates trivial, but you wan't have the peace of mind that the engine will catch any app mistake...

Comment: of course, I can dispense with the unique constraint, but it's incorrect approach, that unique constraint should be :)